# Delete a column

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table and I want to delete the column of a table. I have written a code to delete a particular column.

```
function deleteColumn(index) {
  var total_row = document.getElementById("testBenchTable").rows;
  for (var i=0; i<total_row.length; i++) {
    if (total_row[i].cells.length > 1) {
        total_row[i].deleteCell(index);
    }
  }
```

Now What should do so that I could select a particular column(header) and click on delete so that that particular column gets deleted?

Comment: Could you post the table HTML?

Comment: Hi, the table is generated by using JS. I have put the options to add row and columns.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML it is really difficult to answer your question:)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link for delete column http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tableaddcolumn.html

```
function deleteColumn(tblId)
{
    var allRows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
    for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
        if (allRows[i].cells.length > 1) {
            allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
// 2006-08-21 - Created
// 2006-11-05 - Modified - head and body
function addColumn(tblId)
{
 var tblHeadObj = document.getElementById(tblId).tHead;
 for (var h=0; h<tblHeadObj.rows.length; h++) {
  var newTH = document.createElement('th');
  tblHeadObj.rows[h].appendChild(newTH);
  newTH.innerHTML = '[th] row:' + h + ', cell: ' + (tblHeadObj.rows[h].cells.length - 1)
 }

 var tblBodyObj = document.getElementById(tblId).tBodies[0];
 for (var i=0; i<tblBodyObj.rows.length; i++) {
  var newCell = tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
  newCell.innerHTML = '[td] row:' + i + ', cell: ' + (tblBodyObj.rows[i].cells.length - 1)
 }
}
function deleteColumn(tblId)
{
 var allRows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
 for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
  if (allRows[i].cells.length > 1) {
   allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
<p>
<input type="button" value="add column" onclick="addColumn('tblSample')" />
<input type="button" value="delete column" onclick="deleteColumn('tblSample')" />
</p>
<table id="tblSample" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>[th] row:0, cell: 0</th>
  <th>[th] row:0, cell: 1</th>
  <th>[th] row:0, cell: 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>[td] row:0, cell: 0</td>
  <td>[td] row:0, cell: 1</td>
  <td>[td] row:0, cell: 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>[td] row:1, cell: 0</td>
  <td>[td] row:1, cell: 1</td>
  <td>[td] row:1, cell: 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>[td] row:2, cell: 0</td>
  <td>[td] row:2, cell: 1</td>
  <td>[td] row:2, cell: 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a particular column, you can use the cellIndex of the element (see: [TableData cellIndex Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp))

```js
function deleteColumn(element) {
 var idx = element.cellIndex;
  var total_row = document.getElementById("testBenchTable").rows;
  for (var i=0; i<total_row.length; i++) {
    if (total_row[i].cells.length > 1) {
        total_row[i].deleteCell(idx);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="testBenchTable">
  <tr>
    <th onclick="deleteColumn(this)">Month</th>
    <th onclick="deleteColumn(this)">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function deleteColumn(event) {

var index = event.target.cellIndex;
  var total_row = document.getElementById("testBenchTable").rows;
  for (var i=0; i<total_row.length; i++) {
    if (total_row[i].cells.length > 1) {
        total_row[i].deleteCell(index);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="testBenchTable">
  <tr>
    <th onclick="deleteColumn(event)">Firstname</th>
    <th onclick="deleteColumn(event)">Lastname</th> 
    <th onclick="deleteColumn(event)">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```